# GUI.Label does not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 150, 20), "No-speed circle radious: " + PlayerController.circleradious.ToString());
```

but only `No-speed circle radious:` is on the screen

even if I do

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 150, 20), "No-speed circle radious: " + 100);
```

it is the same. I cannot understand what is my mistake.

All the code:

```
if (GUIEnabled)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 550, 150), "Movement type : " + movementlabel);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 20, 150, 20), "Speed Factor: " + PlayerController.speedFactor.ToString());
            PlayerController.speedFactor = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(160, 25, 350, 20), PlayerController.speedFactor, 0.0F, 100F);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 40, 150, 20), "Velocity: " + (player.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude).ToString());
            if((PlayerController.movement == PlayerController.MoveType.KinectMovement)|| (PlayerController.movement == PlayerController.MoveType.KeyboardMovement)){
                GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 150, 20), "Rotation Factor: " + PlayerController.rotationFactor.ToString());
                PlayerController.rotationFactor = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(160, 65, 350, 20), PlayerController.rotationFactor, 0.0F, 1000F);
                GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 80, 150, 20), "Angular Velocity: " + (player.rigidbody.angularVelocity.magnitude).ToString());
            }
            else if (PlayerController.movement == PlayerController.MoveType.CenterPointKinectWithoutHands) {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 150, 20), "No-speed circle radious: " + PlayerController.circleradious.ToString());
                print(PlayerController.circleradious);
                //PlayerController.circleradious = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(160, 65, 350, 20), PlayerController.circleradious, 0.0F, 20F);
            }
            GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 100, 150, 20), "Camera distance: " + mainCamera.transform.position.y);
            mainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(mainCamera.transform.position.x, GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(160, 105, 350, 20), mainCamera.transform.position.y, 0.0F, 100F), mainCamera.transform.position.z);
        }
```

The other `GUI.Label` work perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried a function that returns a string for that parameter, e.g. string.Concat("No-speed circle radious: ", PlayerController.circleradious.ToString()) or string.Format("No-speed circle radious: {0}", PlayerController.circleradious.ToString())?

Comment: Looks fine. Is the coordinate showing on screen? or it is hiding in background somewhere? Change the coordinates and retry.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that 150px is too short to show the whole message?

Comment: The problem was that it was to short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your rect is too small, try below:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 500, 20), ...);
```

or

---

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(3, 60, 150, 200), ...);
```

and set

```
GUIStyle.wordWrap = true;
```